# Can't get the Mongo portion of my heroku app to work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku

I've looked through several stackoverflow articles and tried different ways of connection but none of them work. So far I've tried:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://Userxxx:Passxxx@ds0URI:PORT/heroku_appXXX';
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } }, function (err, db) {
});
```

That crashed with the following error:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined

Then I tried this:

```
mongo = require('mongodb')
Server = mongo.Server
Db = mongo.Db
BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
con = null;

server = new Server('xxxxx.mongolab.com', 'PORT', {auto_reconnect: true});
DBCon = new Db('xxxxx', server, {safe: false});
DBCon.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
          db.authenticate('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', function(err){
                  if(!err) con = db; 
                 })  
            }   
      });
```

And that gave me an error: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:10
number') throw "host and port must be specified [" + host + ":"  + port + "]"; host and port must be specified

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used MongoClient in Heroku. The code doesn't look that different from what you have:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(databaseString, function (err, result){
     if (err) {
     }
}
```

Because of the error you are getting (MongoClient is undefined), I wonder if your package.json file is correct. In my test it looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.5.x", "mongodb": "1.2.14", "node-static": "0.7.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.x",
        "npm": "1.1.x"
    }
}
```

Comment: My package.json looks just like yours.